# get data from constructor and pass it to variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the data from the constructor and passes it to a variable.

I dont want it to be listed...

Class:

```
class ListaProjetos extends StatefulWidget {
  ListaProjetos({Key key, this.title, this.jsonData}) : super(key: key);

  static const String routeName = "/ListaProjetos";

  final String title;
  final List jsonData;

  @override
  _ListaProjetosState createState() => _ListaProjetosState();
}
```

I want to:

```
class _ListaProjetosState extends State<ListaProjetos> {
  var message = widget.jsonData;

  print(message);
  //HERE I WANT TO PRINT ALL JSON DATA
}
```

Comment: Is not clear what you want, the code seems to be doing what you say in the top, but what means "i dont want it to be listed"?

Comment: it gives me an error that "the instance member widget cant be acessed in an initializer"...
What i want its to get the values from the object and do some calculations on it

Comment: Oh yes, you need to put it inside a method. in the initState can works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the class you need create a method and place the variables initialization, for example:

```
@override
void initState() {
  var message = widget.jsonData;

  print(message);
}
```

Or you can declare the var outside of the method to use it in others methods.

```
var message;

@override
void initState() {
  message = widget.jsonData;

  print(message);
}
```

Comment: Worked it!, i used the second example. but both would solve the problem! tks